# While running selenium script in IE, not able to hover on sub menu in IE

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11, serenity-bdd

I have a scenario where I need to hover on menu1, and again hover on menu 2 and then click on menu3. I am using serenity framework with Java. I am running my script on IE, on Chrome it was working fine.
Below is my sample code used for hovering.

```
System.out.println("Hovering on Report Menu1");
action.moveToElement(menuitemreport).build().perform();
System.out.println("Hovering on online Menu1");
action.moveToElement(menuitemonline).build().perform();
System.out.println("Hovered on online Menu1");
action.moveToElement(menuitemobum).click().build().perform();
```

I am getting error remoter server died. Can you please let me know how to overcome this issue on IE? why it is not working for IE?

Also i used the below code

```
String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript, menuitemroadpricing);
```

For first sub menu it works but from second sub menu it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

"error remoter server died", just with IE? Could be a bug with the IE driver.

Comment: Yes, this is happening only on IE, on chrome it is working perfectly. so i want to know may be it is IE11 issue? Can you let me know in which IE version it can work? PSB error while execution:[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - TEST FAILED AT STEP Navigate to menu on the top bar: Tariff, Road Pricing, Maintain Location, Maintain Distance-based Location
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - The following error occurred: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.